# Aligning two diagrams in tikz environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows, tikz-trees, circuitikz

I have created to diagrams separately using TikZ package and now I want to make them left-right shown in one figure with a caption.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{processblue}{cmyk}{0.96,0,0,0}
\usepgflibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,snakes}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{resizegather}


\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      [scale=0.8,auto=left]
      \node[fill=black,top color=white, bottom color = gray!50,ellipse] (n6) at  (0,-0.5)  {$6=(e,w,w)$};
      \node [fill=black,top color=white, bottom color = gray!50] (n4) at (-3.5,2.5)  {$4=(r,w,p)$};
      \node [fill=black,top color=white, bottom color = gray!50] (n5) at (3.5,2.5)  {$5=(e,w,p)$};
      \node [fill=black,top color=white, bottom color = gray!50] (n2) at (-3.5,5.5) {$2=(r,p,s)$};
      \node [fill=black,top color=white, bottom color = gray!50] (n3) at (3.5,5.5)  {$3=(e,p,s)$};
      \node [fill=black,top color=white, bottom color = gray!50] (n1) at (0,8.5)  {$1=(p,s,s)$};


    \draw  [-stealth] (n1.180) -- (n2.120) node at (-2.7,7.5) {$X$};
    \draw  [-stealth] (n2.20)  -- (n1.230)  node at (-1,6.9) {$Y$};
    \draw  [-stealth] (n2.220)  -- (n4.140)  node at (-4.3,4) {$X$};
    \draw  [-stealth] (-3,2.9)  -- (-3,5.1)  node at (-2.7,4) {$Y$};
    \draw  [-stealth] (n3)  -- (n1)  node at (2.1,7.2) {$Z$};
    \draw  [-stealth] (n3)  -- (n5)  node at (3.8,4) {$X$};
    \draw  [-stealth] (n5)  -- (n6)  node at (2.1,0.9) {$X$};
    \draw  [-stealth] (n2)  -- (n3)  node at (0,5.8) {$T$};
    \draw  [-stealth] (n4)  -- (n5)  node at (0,2.8) {$T'$};
    \draw  [dashed,-stealth] (2.2,2.8)  -- (-2.3,5.16)  node at (0,4.35) {$Z$};
    \draw  [-stealth] (-3.96,2.11)  -- (-1.5,-0.17)  node at (-3.2,0.8) {$X'$};
    \draw  [ dashed,-stealth] (-0.4,0)  -- (-2.8,2.1)  node at (-1.3,1.3) {$Z$};

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}

    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      [scale=0.8,auto=left]
      \node[fill=black,top color=white, bottom color = gray!50,ellipse] (n6) at  (0,-0.5)  {$6=(e,w,w)$};
      \node [fill=black,top color=white, bottom color = gray!50] (n4) at (-3.5,2.5)  {$4=(r,w,p)$};
      \node [fill=black,top color=white, bottom color = gray!50] (n5) at (3.5,2.5)  {$5=(e,w,p)$};
      \node [fill=black,top color=white, bottom color = gray!50] (n2) at (-3.5,5.5) {$2=(r,p,s)$};
      \node [fill=black,top color=white, bottom color = gray!50] (n3) at (3.5,5.5)  {$3=(e,p,s)$};
      \node [fill=black,top color=white, bottom color = gray!50] (n1) at (0,8.5)  {$1=(p,s,s)$};


    \draw  [-stealth] (n1.180) -- (n2.120) node at (-2.7,7.5) {$X$};
    \draw  [-stealth] (n2.20)  -- (n1.230)  node at (-1,6.9) {$Y$};
    \draw  [-stealth] (n2.220)  -- (n4.140)  node at (-4.3,4) {$X$};
    \draw  [-stealth] (-3,2.9)  -- (-3,5.1)  node at (-2.7,4) {$Y$};
    \draw  [-stealth] (n3)  -- (n1)  node at (2.1,7.2) {$Z$};
    \draw  [-stealth] (4,5.1)  -- (4,2.9)  node at (4.3,4) {$X$};
    \draw  [-stealth] (4,2.1)  -- (1.7,-.3)  node at (3.1,0.8) {$X$};
    \draw  [-stealth] (n2)  -- (n3)  node at (0,5.8) {$T$};
    \draw  [-stealth] (n4)  -- (n5)  node at (0,2.8) {$T'$};
    \draw  [dashed,-stealth] (3.1,2.9)  -- (3.1,5.1)  node at (2.8,4) {$Z$};
    \draw  [-stealth] (-3.96,2.11)  -- (-1.5,-0.17)  node at (-3.2,0.8) {$X'$};
    \draw  [ dashed,-stealth] (1,0)  -- (3,2.1)  node at (1.8,1.3) {$Z$};

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: welcome to tex.se! try `begin{figure} \begin{tikzpicture}<code of the first diagram>\end{tikzpicure}\hfill\begin{tikzpicutre}<code for thre second diagram>\end{tikzpicture}\caption{my nice diagrams}\label: fig:...}\end{figure}` ...

Comment: @Zarko thanks for answering my question. I did follow your hint but it did not work out and they are still the same as before.

Comment: @David, than you not follow advise as i propose. or <our page is to narrow to put your images in parallel or we don't understand each other ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

your nice diagrams are to wide that they can be positioned in parallel. you have two options:

- reduce image scale to `0.5`
- increase `\textwidth`

result when the first option is considered:

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{geometry}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{processblue}{cmyk}{0.96,0,0,0}
\usepgflibrary{arrows, shapes, snakes}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{resizegather}

%-------------------------------------- only for show page layout
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.25pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      [scale=0.5,auto=left]  % <--- reduced scale
      \node[fill=black,top color=white, bottom color = gray!50,ellipse] (n6) at  (0,-0.5)  {$6=(e,w,w)$};
      \node [fill=black,top color=white, bottom color = gray!50] (n4) at (-3.5,2.5)  {$4=(r,w,p)$};
      \node [fill=black,top color=white, bottom color = gray!50] (n5) at (3.5,2.5)  {$5=(e,w,p)$};
      \node [fill=black,top color=white, bottom color = gray!50] (n2) at (-3.5,5.5) {$2=(r,p,s)$};
      \node [fill=black,top color=white, bottom color = gray!50] (n3) at (3.5,5.5)  {$3=(e,p,s)$};
      \node [fill=black,top color=white, bottom color = gray!50] (n1) at (0,8.5)  {$1=(p,s,s)$};
    \draw  [-stealth] (n1.180) -- (n2.120) node at (-2.7,7.5) {$X$};
    \draw  [-stealth] (n2.20)  -- (n1.230)  node at (-1,6.9) {$Y$};
    \draw  [-stealth] (n2.220)  -- (n4.140)  node at (-4.3,4) {$X$};
    \draw  [-stealth] (-3,2.9)  -- (-3,5.1)  node at (-2.7,4) {$Y$};
    \draw  [-stealth] (n3)  -- (n1)  node at (2.1,7.2) {$Z$};
    \draw  [-stealth] (n3)  -- (n5)  node at (3.8,4) {$X$};
    \draw  [-stealth] (n5)  -- (n6)  node at (2.1,0.9) {$X$};
    \draw  [-stealth] (n2)  -- (n3)  node at (0,5.8) {$T$};
    \draw  [-stealth] (n4)  -- (n5)  node at (0,2.8) {$T'$};
    \draw  [dashed,-stealth] (2.2,2.8)  -- (-2.3,5.16)  node at (0,4.35) {$Z$};
    \draw  [-stealth] (-3.96,2.11)  -- (-1.5,-0.17)  node at (-3.2,0.8) {$X'$};
    \draw  [ dashed,-stealth] (-0.4,0)  -- (-2.8,2.1)  node at (-1.3,1.3) {$Z$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \hfil
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      [scale=0.5,auto=left]  % <--- reduced scale
      \node[fill=black,top color=white, bottom color = gray!50,ellipse] (n6) at  (0,-0.5)  {$6=(e,w,w)$};
      \node [fill=black,top color=white, bottom color = gray!50] (n4) at (-3.5,2.5)  {$4=(r,w,p)$};
      \node [fill=black,top color=white, bottom color = gray!50] (n5) at (3.5,2.5)  {$5=(e,w,p)$};
      \node [fill=black,top color=white, bottom color = gray!50] (n2) at (-3.5,5.5) {$2=(r,p,s)$};
      \node [fill=black,top color=white, bottom color = gray!50] (n3) at (3.5,5.5)  {$3=(e,p,s)$};
      \node [fill=black,top color=white, bottom color = gray!50] (n1) at (0,8.5)  {$1=(p,s,s)$};
    \draw  [-stealth] (n1.180) -- (n2.120) node at (-2.7,7.5) {$X$};
    \draw  [-stealth] (n2.20)  -- (n1.230)  node at (-1,6.9) {$Y$};
    \draw  [-stealth] (n2.220)  -- (n4.140)  node at (-4.3,4) {$X$};
    \draw  [-stealth] (-3,2.9)  -- (-3,5.1)  node at (-2.7,4) {$Y$};
    \draw  [-stealth] (n3)  -- (n1)  node at (2.1,7.2) {$Z$};
    \draw  [-stealth] (4,5.1)  -- (4,2.9)  node at (4.3,4) {$X$};
    \draw  [-stealth] (4,2.1)  -- (1.7,-.3)  node at (3.1,0.8) {$X$};
    \draw  [-stealth] (n2)  -- (n3)  node at (0,5.8) {$T$};
    \draw  [-stealth] (n4)  -- (n5)  node at (0,2.8) {$T'$};
    \draw  [dashed,-stealth] (3.1,2.9)  -- (3.1,5.1)  node at (2.8,4) {$Z$};
    \draw  [-stealth] (-3.96,2.11)  -- (-1.5,-0.17)  node at (-3.2,0.8) {$X'$};
    \draw  [ dashed,-stealth] (1,0)  -- (3,2.1)  node at (1.8,1.3) {$Z$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{My nice digrams}
        \label{fig:test}
    \end{figure}
    see my nice diagrams in figure \ref{fig:test} \dots

\end{document}
```

**edit:** off-topic:
your diagram code can be significantly shortened if you define nodes style and use `quotes` libraries for labeling of arrows. with relative positioning of nodes you can improve positioning of arrows between node.

**edit (2)**: considering of the @marmot comment, the first proposed diagram's code can be further improved with the same size of rectangle shaped nodes. with this code you can fit the both diagrams in text width without scaling down of the of image size. with common `\tikset` for both diagrams the code become even shorter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, quotes}
\usepgflibrary{arrows.meta, shapes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \tikzset{
        node distance = 11mm and 6mm,
   box/.style = {rectangle, draw=gray!25, thin,
                 top color=white, bottom color = gray!50,
                 text height=1.5ex, text depth=0.25ex,
                 minimum width=6em},
 ellip/.style = {ellipse, draw=gray!25, thin,
                 top color=white, bottom color = gray!50},
    sx/.style = {xshift=#1mm},
every edge quotes/.append style = {font=\footnotesize,
                                   inner sep=1pt, auto=right},
every edge/.append style = {-Stealth}
                }
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\node (n6) [ellip]  {$6=(e,w,w)$};
\node (n4) [box, above  left=of n6.north]   {$4=(r,w,p)$};
\node (n5) [box, above right=of n6.north]   {$5=(e,w,p)$};
\node (n2) [box, above=of n4]               {$2=(r,p,s)$};
\node (n3) [box, above=of n5]               {$3=(e,p,s)$};
\node (n1) [box, above=of n2 -| n6]         {$1=(p,s,s)$};
%
\draw       ([sx=-6] n1.south)  edge ["$X$"] ([sx=-2] n2.north)
            ([sx= 2] n2.north)  edge ["$Y$"] ([sx=-2] n1.south)
            ([sx=-2] n2.south)  edge ["$X$"] ([sx=-2] n4.north)
            ([sx= 2] n4.north)  edge ["$Y$"] ([sx= 2] n2.south)
            ([sx=-2] n4.south)  edge ["$X$"] (n6.150)
            (n6.120)            edge ["$Z$", dashed] ([sx=3] n4.south)
%
            ([sx=-2] n3.north)  edge ["$Z$"] ([sx= 2] n1.south)
            (n3.south)          edge ["$X$"] (n5.north)
            (n5.south)          edge ["$X$"] (n6.45)
            ([sx=-4] n5.north)  edge ["$Z$", dashed] ([sx=6] n2.south)
                        (n2)    edge ["$T$"  '] (n3)
                        (n4)    edge ["$T'$" '] (n5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \hfil
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\node (n6) [ellip]  {$6=(e,w,w)$};
\node (n4) [box, above  left=of n6.north]   {$4=(r,w,p)$};
\node (n5) [box, above right=of n6.north]   {$5=(e,w,p)$};
\node (n2) [box, above=of n4]               {$2=(r,p,s)$};
\node (n3) [box, above=of n5]               {$3=(e,p,s)$};
\node (n1) [box, above=of n2 -| n6]         {$1=(p,s,s)$};
%
\draw       ([sx=-6] n1.south)  edge ["$X$"] ([sx=-2] n2.north)
            ([sx= 2] n2.north)  edge ["$Y$"] ([sx=-2] n1.south)
            ([sx=-2] n2.south)  edge ["$X$"] ([sx=-2] n4.north)
            ([sx= 2] n4.north)  edge ["$Y$"] ([sx= 2] n2.south)
            ([sx=-2] n4.south)  edge ["$X$"] (n6.150)
            (n6.120)            edge ["$Z$", dashed] ([sx=3] n4.south)
%
            ([sx=-2] n3.north)  edge ["$Z$"] ([sx= 2] n1.south)
            (n3.south)          edge ["$X$"] (n5.north)
            (n5.south)          edge ["$X$"] (n6.45)
            ([sx=-4] n5.north)  edge ["$Z$", dashed] ([sx=6] n2.south)
                        (n2)    edge ["$T$"  '] (n3)
                        (n4)    edge ["$T'$" '] (n5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{My nice digrams}
        \label{fig:test}
    \end{figure}
    see my nice diagrams in figure \ref{fig:test} \dots
\end{document}
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: @marmot, thank you very much! good idea. as second step in improvement of the op diagram :-)

Comment: @marmot, you are right. they left from op mwe, but in my mwe are not needed.

Answer (score 2):

To align figures created with `TikZ`, the easiest way is to use the **power of TikZ** which is precisely made for this purpose: to make figures and place them where you want!

Thus, it is sufficient to place the second diagram in a `scope` environment and move it. I have commented on the lines that are no longer necessary.

```
%    \end{tikzpicture}
%    \end{center}
%
%    \begin{center}
%    \begin{tikzpicture}
%      [scale=0.8,auto=left]
\begin{scope}[xshift=11cm]
```

To place a caption, simply place it with the `TikZ` operation specially dedicated to it: a `node`!

```
\node[below=5mm of my diagram.south] {My caption};
```

If your document must be written in the `article` class, so that the diagrams contain in the page without overflowing in the margins, it is necessary to reduce, here I reduced with a factor `0.55`. To view these margins, I loaded the `showframe` package.

```
\usepackage{showframe}
```

Depending on your margins, or the final `class` in which you write your document, you can change this `factor`.

And to make it even simpler, it can be placed relative to the two diagrams by creating a `local bounding box`, here called `my diagrams`, which allows the node to be placed in the same position regardless of the dimensions of the diagrams.

```
\begin{scope}[local bounding box=my diagrams]
```

I created the style called `upper` to lighten the code, and I factorized the definition of the `arrow.`

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.55,auto=left,upper/.style={fill=black,top color=white, bottom color = gray!50},>=stealth]
```

[image: diagrmmes]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{processblue}{cmyk}{0.96,0,0,0}
\usepgflibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,snakes,positioning}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{resizegather}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.55,auto=left,
                        upper/.style={fill=black,top color=white, bottom color = gray!50},
                        >=stealth]
    \begin{scope}[local bounding box=my diagrams]
    \node[upper,ellipse] (n6) at  (0,-0.5)  {$6=(e,w,w)$};
      \node [upper] (n4) at (-3.5,2.5)  {$4=(r,w,p)$};
      \node [upper] (n5) at (3.5,2.5)  {$5=(e,w,p)$};
      \node [upper] (n2) at (-3.5,5.5) {$2=(r,p,s)$};
      \node [upper] (n3) at (3.5,5.5)  {$3=(e,p,s)$};
      \node [upper] (n1) at (0,8.5)  {$1=(p,s,s)$};

    \draw  [->] (n1.180) -- (n2.120) node at (-2.7,7.5) {$X$};
    \draw  [->] (n2.20)  -- (n1.230)  node at (-1,6.9) {$Y$};
    \draw  [->] (n2.220)  -- (n4.140)  node at (-4.3,4) {$X$};
    \draw  [->] (-3,2.9)  -- (-3,5.1)  node at (-2.7,4) {$Y$};
    \draw  [->] (n3)  -- (n1)  node at (2.1,7.2) {$Z$};
    \draw  [->] (n3)  -- (n5)  node at (3.8,4) {$X$};
    \draw  [->] (n5)  -- (n6)  node at (2.1,0.9) {$X$};
    \draw  [->] (n2)  -- (n3)  node at (0,5.8) {$T$};
    \draw  [->] (n4)  -- (n5)  node at (0,2.8) {$T'$};
    \draw  [dashed,->] (2.2,2.8)  -- (-2.3,5.16)  node at (0,4.35) {$Z$};
    \draw  [->] (-3.96,2.11)  -- (-1.5,-0.17)  node at (-3.2,0.8) {$X'$};
    \draw  [ dashed,->] (-0.4,0)  -- (-2.8,2.1)  node at (-1.3,1.3) {$Z$};

%    \end{tikzpicture}
%    \end{center}
%
%    \begin{center}
%    \begin{tikzpicture}
%      [scale=0.8,auto=left]
\begin{scope}[xshift=11cm]
\node[upper,ellipse] (n6) at  (0,-0.5)  {$6=(e,w,w)$};
      \node [upper] (n4) at (-3.5,2.5)  {$4=(r,w,p)$};
      \node [upper] (n5) at (3.5,2.5)  {$5=(e,w,p)$};
      \node [upper] (n2) at (-3.5,5.5) {$2=(r,p,s)$};
      \node [upper] (n3) at (3.5,5.5)  {$3=(e,p,s)$};
      \node [upper] (n1) at (0,8.5)  {$1=(p,s,s)$};

    \draw  [->] (n1.180) -- (n2.120) node at (-2.7,7.5) {$X$};
    \draw  [->] (n2.20)  -- (n1.230)  node at (-1,6.9) {$Y$};
    \draw  [->] (n2.220)  -- (n4.140)  node at (-4.3,4) {$X$};
    \draw  [->] (-3,2.9)  -- (-3,5.1)  node at (-2.7,4) {$Y$};
    \draw  [->] (n3)  -- (n1)  node at (2.1,7.2) {$Z$};
    \draw  [->] (4,5.1)  -- (4,2.9)  node at (4.3,4) {$X$};
    \draw  [->] (4,2.1)  -- (1.7,-.3)  node at (3.1,0.8) {$X$};
    \draw  [->] (n2)  -- (n3)  node at (0,5.8) {$T$};
    \draw  [->] (n4)  -- (n5)  node at (0,2.8) {$T'$};
    \draw  [dashed,->] (3.1,2.9)  -- (3.1,5.1)  node at (2.8,4) {$Z$};
    \draw  [->] (-3.96,2.11)  -- (-1.5,-0.17)  node at (-3.2,0.8) {$X'$};
    \draw  [ dashed,->] (1,0)  -- (3,2.1)  node at (1.8,1.3) {$Z$};
\end{scope}
\end{scope}      
\node[below=5mm of my diagrams.south] {My caption};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}

\end{document}
```

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator